# Поиск дубликатов в словарях

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно найти повторяющиеся "ключ-значение" в двух словарях и добавить из в третий словарь? Единственный метод, который мне удалось найти, это превратить "ключ-значение" в tuple и уже там конвертировать обратно в словарь. Однако, код получается громоздкий. Есть ли более простые способы?

Словарь 1:

```
{'BNB': 'BTC', 'NULS': 'BTC', 'NEO': 'BTC', 'LINK': 'BTC', 'IOTA': 'BTC', 'ETC': 'BTC', 'KNC': 'BTC', 'WTC': 'BTC', 'SNGLS': 'BTC', 'GAS': 'BTC', 'SNM': 'BTC', 'BQX': 'BTC', 'QTUM': 'BTC', 'LTC': 'BTC', 'ETH': 'BTC', 'ZRX': 'BTC', 'OMG': 'BTC', '1INCH': 'BTC', 'AAVE': 'BTC', 'ADA': 'BTC', 'ADX': 'BTC', 'AERGO': 'BTC', 'AGI': 'BTC', 'AION': 'BTC', 'AKRO': 'BTC', 'ALGO': 'BTC', 'ALPHA': 'BTC', 'AMB': 'BTC', 'ANKR': 'BTC', 'APPC': 'BTC', 'ARDR': 'BTC', 'ARK': 'BTC', 'ARPA': 'BTC', 'ASR': 'BTC', 'AST': 'BTC', 'ATM': 'BTC', 'ATOM': 'BTC', 'AUDIO': 'BTC', 'AVA': 'BTC', 'AVAX': 'BTC', 'AXS': 'BTC', 'BAND': 'BTC', 'BAT': 'BTC', 'BCD': 'BTC', 'BCH': 'BTC', 'BCPT': 'BTC', 'BEAM': 'BTC', 'BEL': 'BTC', 'BLZ': 'BTC', 'BNT': 'BTC', 'BOT': 'BTC', 'BRD': 'BTC', 'BTCST': 'BTC', 'BTG': 'BTC', 'BTS': 'BTC', 'BZRX': 'BTC', 'CDT': 'BTC', 'CELO': 'BTC', 'CELR': 'BTC', 'CHR': 'BTC', 'CHZ': 'BTC', 'CKB': 'BTC', 'CND': 'BTC', 'COMP': 'BTC', 'COS': 'BTC', 'COTI': 'BTC', 'CRV': 'BTC', 'CTK': 'BTC', 'CTSI': 'BTC', 'CTXC': 'BTC', 'CVC': 'BTC', 'DASH': 'BTC', 'DATA': 'BTC', 'DCR': 'BTC', 'DIA': 'BTC', 'DLT': 'BTC', 'DNT': 'BTC', 'DOCK': 'BTC', 'DOGE': 'BTC', 'DOT': 'BTC', 'DREP': 'BTC', 'DUSK': 'BTC', 'EGLD': 'BTC', 'ELF': 'BTC', 'ENJ': 'BTC', 'EOS': 'BTC', 'EVX': 'BTC', 'FET': 'BTC', 'FIL': 'BTC', 'FIO': 'BTC', 'FIRO': 'BTC', 'FLM': 'BTC', 'FOR': 'BTC', 'FTM': 'BTC', 'FTT': 'BTC', 'FUN': 'BTC', 'GLM': 'BTC', 'GO': 'BTC', 'GRS': 'BTC', 'GRT': 'BTC', 'GTO': 'BTC', 'GVT': 'BTC', 'GXS': 'BTC', 'HARD': 'BTC', 'HBAR': 'BTC', 'HIVE': 'BTC', 'HNT': 'BTC', 'ICX': 'BTC', 'IDEX': 'BTC', 'INJ': 'BTC', 'IOST': 'BTC', 'IOTX': 'BTC', 'IRIS': 'BTC', 'JST': 'BTC', 'JUV': 'BTC', 'KAVA': 'BTC', 'KMD': 'BTC', 'LIT': 'BTC', 'LOOM': 'BTC', 'LRC': 'BTC', 'LSK': 'BTC', 'LTO': 'BTC', 'LUNA': 'BTC', 'MANA': 'BTC', 'MATIC': 'BTC', 'MDA': 'BTC', 'MDT': 'BTC', 'MITH': 'BTC', 'MKR': 'BTC', 'MTH': 'BTC', 'MTL': 'BTC', 'NANO': 'BTC', 'NAS': 'BTC', 'NAV': 'BTC', 'NBS': 'BTC', 'NEAR': 'BTC', 'NEBL': 'BTC', 'NKN': 'BTC', 'NMR': 'BTC', 'NXS': 'BTC', 'OAX': 'BTC', 'OCEAN': 'BTC', 'OG': 'BTC', 'OGN': 'BTC', 'ONE': 'BTC', 'ONG': 'BTC', 'ONT': 'BTC', 'ORN': 'BTC', 'OST': 'BTC', 'OXT': 'BTC', 'PAXG': 'BTC', 'PERL': 'BTC', 'PHB': 'BTC', 'PIVX': 'BTC', 'PNT': 'BTC', 'POA': 'BTC', 'POLY': 'BTC', 'POWR': 'BTC', 'PPT': 'BTC', 'PSG': 'BTC', 'QKC': 'BTC', 'QLC': 'BTC', 'QSP': 'BTC', 'RCN': 'BTC', 'RDN': 'BTC', 'REEF': 'BTC', 'REN': 'BTC', 'RENBTC': 'BTC', 'REP': 'BTC', 'REQ': 'BTC', 'RIF': 'BTC', 'RLC': 'BTC', 'ROSE': 'BTC', 'RSR': 'BTC', 'RUNE': 'BTC', 'RVN': 'BTC', 'SAND': 'BTC', 'SC': 'BTC', 'SCRT': 'BTC', 'SKL': 'BTC', 'SKY': 'BTC', 'SNT': 'BTC', 'SNX': 'BTC', 'SOL': 'BTC', 'SRM': 'BTC', 'STEEM': 'BTC', 'STMX': 'BTC', 'STORJ': 'BTC', 'STPT': 'BTC', 'STRAX': 'BTC', 'STX': 'BTC', 'SUN': 'BTC', 'SUSD': 'BTC', 'SUSHI': 'BTC', 'SXP': 'BTC', 'SYS': 'BTC', 'TCT': 'BTC', 'TFUEL': 'BTC', 'THETA': 'BTC', 'TNB': 'BTC', 'TOMO': 'BTC', 'TRB': 'BTC', 'TROY': 'BTC', 'TRU': 'BTC', 'TRX': 'BTC', 'TWT': 'BTC', 'UMA': 'BTC', 'UNFI': 'BTC', 'UNI': 'BTC', 'UTK': 'BTC', 'VET': 'BTC', 'VIA': 'BTC', 'VIB': 'BTC', 'VIBE': 'BTC', 'VIDT': 'BTC', 'VITE': 'BTC', 'WABI': 'BTC', 'WAN': 'BTC', 'WAVES': 'BTC', 'WBTC': 'BTC', 'WING': 'BTC', 'WNXM': 'BTC', 'WPR': 'BTC', 'WRX': 'BTC', 'XEM': 'BTC', 'XLM':
'BTC', 'XMR': 'BTC', 'XRP': 'BTC', 'XTZ': 'BTC', 'XVG': 'BTC', 'XVS': 'BTC', 'XZC': 'BTC', 'YFI': 'BTC', 'YFII': 'BTC', 'YOYO': 'BTC', 'ZEC': 'BTC', 'ZEN': 'BTC', 'ZIL': 'BTC', 'DGB': 'BTC', 'BAL': 'BTC', 'ANT': 'BTC', 'KSM': 'BTC'}
```

Словарь 2:

```
{'AAVE': 'BTC', 'ADA': 'BTC', 'ALGO': 'BTC', 'ALPHA': 'BTC', 'ANKR': 'BTC', 'ARPA': 'BTC', 'ATOM': 'BTC', 'AVA': 'BTC', 'AVAX': 'BTC', 'AXS': 'BTC', 'BAND': 'BTC', 'BAT': 'BTC', 'BCH': 'BTC', 'BEL': 'BTC', 'BLZ': 'BTC', 'CELR': 'BTC', 'CHR': 'BTC', 'CHZ': 'BTC', 'COS': 'BTC', 'COTI': 'BTC', 'CRV': 'BTC', 'CTK': 'BTC', 'CTSI': 'BTC', 'DASH': 'BTC', 'DIA': 'BTC', 'DOT': 'BTC', 'EGLD': 'BTC', 'ENJ': 'BTC', 'EOS': 'BTC', 'FET': 'BTC', 'FIL': 'BTC', 'FIO': 'BTC', 'FTM': 'BTC', 'FTT': 'BTC', 'HARD': 'BTC', 'HBAR': 'BTC', 'ICX': 'BTC', 'INJ': 'BTC', 'IOST': 'BTC', 'JST': 'BTC', 'KAVA': 'BTC', 'LUNA': 'BTC', 'MATIC': 'BTC', 'MITH': 'BTC', 'MKR': 'BTC', 'NEAR': 'BTC', 'NMR': 'BTC', 'OCEAN': 'BTC', 'OGN': 'BTC', 'ONE': 'BTC', 'ONT': 'BTC', 'PAXG': 'BTC', 'PERL': 'BTC', 'RSR': 'BTC', 'RUNE': 'BTC', 'RVN': 'BTC', 'SAND': 'BTC', 'SC': 'BTC', 'SNX': 'BTC', 'SOL': 'BTC', 'SRM': 'BTC', 'STMX': 'BTC', 'STX':
'BTC', 'SUSHI': 'BTC', 'SXP': 'BTC', 'THETA': 'BTC', 'TROY': 'BTC', 'TRX': 'BTC', 'UNFI': 'BTC', 'UNI': 'BTC', 'VET': 'BTC', 'WABI': 'BTC', 'WAN': 'BTC', 'WAVES': 'BTC', 'WING': 'BTC', 'WNXM': 'BTC', 'WRX': 'BTC', 'XLM': 'BTC', 'XMR': 'BTC', 'XRP': 'BTC', 'XTZ': 'BTC', 'XVG': 'BTC', 'XVS': 'BTC', 'YFI': 'BTC', 'YFII': 'BTC', 'ZEC': 'BTC', 'ZEN': 'BTC', 'ZIL':
'BTC', 'DGB': 'BTC', 'ANT': 'BTC', 'KSM': 'BTC'}
```

Словарь 3 должен содержать одинаковые "ключ-значение", которые есть в обоих словарях.

```
voc = []
```

Comment: У вас кажется весь второй словарь целиком содержится в первом. Это нормально? )

Comment: результат voc должен быть списком или, все-таки, словарем?

Comment: Да, вы скорее всего правы. В первом словаре, скорее всего, есть всего значения из второго. Однако данная модель применима только к одному данному словарю. Все из-за популярности BTC. Однако, если повторить процедуру с другими валютами, то далеко не факт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Циклом, без преобразования в кортежи:

```
a = {'BNB': 'BTC', 'NULS': 'BTC', 'NEO': 'BTC', 'LINK': 'BTC', 'IOTA': 'BTC', 'ETC': 'BTC', 'KNC': 'BTC', 'WTC': 'BTC', 'SNGLS': 'BTC', 'GAS': 'BTC', 'SNM': 'BTC', 'BQX': 'BTC', 'QTUM': 'BTC', 'LTC': 'BTC', 'ETH': 'BTC', 'ZRX': 'BTC', 'OMG': 'BTC', '1INCH': 'BTC', 'AAVE': 'BTC', 'ADA': 'BTC', 'ADX': 'BTC', 'AERGO': 'BTC', 'AGI': 'BTC', 'AION': 'BTC', 'AKRO': 'BTC', 'ALGO': 'BTC', 'ALPHA': 'BTC', 'AMB': 'BTC', 'ANKR': 'BTC', 'APPC': 'BTC', 'ARDR': 'BTC', 'ARK': 'BTC', 'ARPA': 'BTC', 'ASR': 'BTC', 'AST': 'BTC', 'ATM': 'BTC', 'ATOM': 'BTC', 'AUDIO': 'BTC', 'AVA': 'BTC', 'AVAX': 'BTC', 'AXS': 'BTC', 'BAND': 'BTC', 'BAT': 'BTC', 'BCD': 'BTC', 'BCH': 'BTC', 'BCPT': 'BTC', 'BEAM': 'BTC', 'BEL': 'BTC', 'BLZ': 'BTC', 'BNT': 'BTC', 'BOT': 'BTC', 'BRD': 'BTC', 'BTCST': 'BTC', 'BTG': 'BTC', 'BTS': 'BTC', 'BZRX': 'BTC', 'CDT': 'BTC', 'CELO': 'BTC', 'CELR': 'BTC', 'CHR': 'BTC', 'CHZ': 'BTC', 'CKB': 'BTC', 'CND': 'BTC', 'COMP': 'BTC', 'COS': 'BTC', 'COTI': 'BTC', 'CRV': 'BTC', 'CTK': 'BTC', 'CTSI': 'BTC', 'CTXC': 'BTC', 'CVC': 'BTC', 'DASH': 'BTC', 'DATA': 'BTC', 'DCR': 'BTC', 'DIA': 'BTC', 'DLT': 'BTC', 'DNT': 'BTC', 'DOCK': 'BTC', 'DOGE': 'BTC', 'DOT': 'BTC', 'DREP': 'BTC', 'DUSK': 'BTC', 'EGLD': 'BTC', 'ELF': 'BTC', 'ENJ': 'BTC', 'EOS': 'BTC', 'EVX': 'BTC', 'FET': 'BTC', 'FIL': 'BTC', 'FIO': 'BTC', 'FIRO': 'BTC', 'FLM': 'BTC', 'FOR': 'BTC', 'FTM': 'BTC', 'FTT': 'BTC', 'FUN': 'BTC', 'GLM': 'BTC', 'GO': 'BTC', 'GRS': 'BTC', 'GRT': 'BTC', 'GTO': 'BTC', 'GVT': 'BTC', 'GXS': 'BTC', 'HARD': 'BTC', 'HBAR': 'BTC', 'HIVE': 'BTC', 'HNT': 'BTC', 'ICX': 'BTC', 'IDEX': 'BTC', 'INJ': 'BTC', 'IOST': 'BTC', 'IOTX': 'BTC', 'IRIS': 'BTC', 'JST': 'BTC', 'JUV': 'BTC', 'KAVA': 'BTC', 'KMD': 'BTC', 'LIT': 'BTC', 'LOOM': 'BTC', 'LRC': 'BTC', 'LSK': 'BTC', 'LTO': 'BTC', 'LUNA': 'BTC', 'MANA': 'BTC', 'MATIC': 'BTC', 'MDA': 'BTC', 'MDT': 'BTC', 'MITH': 'BTC', 'MKR': 'BTC', 'MTH': 'BTC', 'MTL': 'BTC', 'NANO': 'BTC', 'NAS': 'BTC', 'NAV': 'BTC', 'NBS': 'BTC', 'NEAR': 'BTC', 'NEBL': 'BTC', 'NKN': 'BTC', 'NMR': 'BTC', 'NXS': 'BTC', 'OAX': 'BTC', 'OCEAN': 'BTC', 'OG': 'BTC', 'OGN': 'BTC', 'ONE': 'BTC', 'ONG': 'BTC', 'ONT': 'BTC', 'ORN': 'BTC', 'OST': 'BTC', 'OXT': 'BTC', 'PAXG': 'BTC', 'PERL': 'BTC', 'PHB': 'BTC', 'PIVX': 'BTC', 'PNT': 'BTC', 'POA': 'BTC', 'POLY': 'BTC', 'POWR': 'BTC', 'PPT': 'BTC', 'PSG': 'BTC', 'QKC': 'BTC', 'QLC': 'BTC', 'QSP': 'BTC', 'RCN': 'BTC', 'RDN': 'BTC', 'REEF': 'BTC', 'REN': 'BTC', 'RENBTC': 'BTC', 'REP': 'BTC', 'REQ': 'BTC', 'RIF': 'BTC', 'RLC': 'BTC', 'ROSE': 'BTC', 'RSR': 'BTC', 'RUNE': 'BTC', 'RVN': 'BTC', 'SAND': 'BTC', 'SC': 'BTC', 'SCRT': 'BTC', 'SKL': 'BTC', 'SKY': 'BTC', 'SNT': 'BTC', 'SNX': 'BTC', 'SOL': 'BTC', 'SRM': 'BTC', 'STEEM': 'BTC', 'STMX': 'BTC', 'STORJ': 'BTC', 'STPT': 'BTC', 'STRAX': 'BTC', 'STX': 'BTC', 'SUN': 'BTC', 'SUSD': 'BTC', 'SUSHI': 'BTC', 'SXP': 'BTC', 'SYS': 'BTC', 'TCT': 'BTC', 'TFUEL': 'BTC', 'THETA': 'BTC', 'TNB': 'BTC', 'TOMO': 'BTC', 'TRB': 'BTC', 'TROY': 'BTC', 'TRU': 'BTC', 'TRX': 'BTC', 'TWT': 'BTC', 'UMA': 'BTC', 'UNFI': 'BTC', 'UNI': 'BTC', 'UTK': 'BTC', 'VET': 'BTC', 'VIA': 'BTC', 'VIB': 'BTC', 'VIBE': 'BTC', 'VIDT': 'BTC', 'VITE': 'BTC', 'WABI': 'BTC', 'WAN': 'BTC', 'WAVES': 'BTC', 'WBTC': 'BTC', 'WING': 'BTC', 'WNXM': 'BTC', 'WPR': 'BTC', 'WRX': 'BTC', 'XEM': 'BTC', 'XLM': 'BTC', 'XMR': 'BTC', 'XRP': 'BTC', 'XTZ': 'BTC', 'XVG': 'BTC', 'XVS': 'BTC', 'XZC': 'BTC', 'YFI': 'BTC', 'YFII': 'BTC', 'YOYO': 'BTC', 'ZEC': 'BTC', 'ZEN': 'BTC', 'ZIL': 'BTC', 'DGB': 'BTC', 'BAL': 'BTC', 'ANT': 'BTC', 'KSM': 'BTC'}
b = {'AAVE': 'BTC', 'ADA': 'BTC', 'ALGO': 'BTC', 'ALPHA': 'BTC', 'ANKR': 'BTC', 'ARPA': 'BTC', 'ATOM': 'BTC', 'AVA': 'BTC', 'AVAX': 'BTC', 'AXS': 'BTC', 'BAND': 'BTC', 'BAT': 'BTC', 'BCH': 'BTC', 'BEL': 'BTC', 'BLZ': 'BTC', 'CELR': 'BTC', 'CHR': 'BTC', 'CHZ': 'BTC', 'COS': 'BTC', 'COTI': 'BTC', 'CRV': 'BTC', 'CTK': 'BTC', 'CTSI': 'BTC', 'DASH': 'BTC', 'DIA': 'BTC', 'DOT': 'BTC', 'EGLD': 'BTC', 'ENJ': 'BTC', 'EOS': 'BTC', 'FET': 'BTC', 'FIL': 'BTC', 'FIO': 'BTC', 'FTM': 'BTC', 'FTT': 'BTC', 'HARD': 'BTC', 'HBAR': 'BTC', 'ICX': 'BTC', 'INJ': 'BTC', 'IOST': 'BTC', 'JST': 'BTC', 'KAVA': 'BTC', 'LUNA': 'BTC', 'MATIC': 'BTC', 'MITH': 'BTC', 'MKR': 'BTC', 'NEAR': 'BTC', 'NMR': 'BTC', 'OCEAN': 'BTC', 'OGN': 'BTC', 'ONE': 'BTC', 'ONT': 'BTC', 'PAXG': 'BTC', 'PERL': 'BTC', 'RSR': 'BTC', 'RUNE': 'BTC', 'RVN': 'BTC', 'SAND': 'BTC', 'SC': 'BTC', 'SNX': 'BTC', 'SOL': 'BTC', 'SRM': 'BTC', 'STMX': 'BTC', 'STX': 'BTC', 'SUSHI': 'BTC', 'SXP': 'BTC', 'THETA': 'BTC', 'TROY': 'BTC', 'TRX': 'BTC', 'UNFI': 'BTC', 'UNI': 'BTC', 'VET': 'BTC', 'WABI': 'BTC', 'WAN': 'BTC', 'WAVES': 'BTC', 'WING': 'BTC', 'WNXM': 'BTC', 'WRX': 'BTC', 'XLM': 'BTC', 'XMR': 'BTC', 'XRP': 'BTC', 'XTZ': 'BTC', 'XVG': 'BTC', 'XVS': 'BTC', 'YFI': 'BTC', 'YFII': 'BTC', 'ZEC': 'BTC', 'ZEN': 'BTC', 'ZIL':'BTC', 'DGB': 'BTC', 'ANT': 'BTC', 'KSM': 'BTC'}

c = {k: a[k] for k in a if k in b and a[k] == b[k]}
```

В результате в `с`:

```
>>> c
{'AAVE': 'BTC', 'ADA': 'BTC', 'ALGO': 'BTC', 'ALPHA': 'BTC', 'ANKR': 'BTC', 'ARPA': 'BTC', 'ATOM': 'BTC', 'AVA': 'BTC', 'AVAX': 'BTC', 'AXS': 'BTC', 'BAND': 'BTC', 'BAT': 'BTC', 'BCH': 'BTC', 'BEL': 'BTC', 'BLZ': 'BTC', 'CELR': 'BTC', 'CHR': 'BTC', 'CHZ': 'BTC', 'COS': 'BTC', 'COTI': 'BTC', 'CRV': 'BTC', 'CTK': 'BTC', 'CTSI': 'BTC', 'DASH': 'BTC', 'DIA': 'BTC', 'DOT': 'BTC', 'EGLD': 'BTC', 'ENJ': 'BTC', 'EOS': 'BTC', 'FET': 'BTC', 'FIL': 'BTC', 'FIO': 'BTC', 'FTM': 'BTC', 'FTT': 'BTC', 'HARD': 'BTC', 'HBAR': 'BTC', 'ICX': 'BTC', 'INJ': 'BTC', 'IOST': 'BTC', 'JST': 'BTC', 'KAVA': 'BTC', 'LUNA': 'BTC', 'MATIC': 'BTC', 'MITH': 'BTC', 'MKR': 'BTC', 'NEAR': 'BTC', 'NMR': 'BTC', 'OCEAN': 'BTC', 'OGN': 'BTC', 'ONE': 'BTC', 'ONT': 'BTC', 'PAXG': 'BTC', 'PERL': 'BTC', 'RSR': 'BTC', 'RUNE': 'BTC', 'RVN': 'BTC', 'SAND': 'BTC', 'SC': 'BTC', 'SNX': 'BTC', 'SOL': 'BTC', 'SRM': 'BTC', 'STMX': 'BTC', 'STX': 'BTC', 'SUSHI': 'BTC', 'SXP': 'BTC', 'THETA': 'BTC', 'TROY': 'BTC', 'TRX': 'BTC', 'UNFI': 'BTC', 'UNI': 'BTC', 'VET': 'BTC', 'WABI': 'BTC', 'WAN': 'BTC', 'WAVES': 'BTC', 'WING': 'BTC', 'WNXM': 'BTC', 'WRX': 'BTC', 'XLM': 'BTC', 'XMR': 'BTC', 'XRP': 'BTC', 'XTZ': 'BTC', 'XVG': 'BTC', 'XVS': 'BTC', 'YFI': 'BTC', 'YFII': 'BTC', 'ZEC': 'BTC', 'ZEN': 'BTC', 'ZIL': 'BTC', 'DGB': 'BTC', 'ANT': 'BTC', 'KSM': 'BTC'}
```

---

**UPD** Для "понимания конструкции..." почитайте [dictionary comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension):

```
result_dict = dict()

# для каждого ключа в первом словаре 
for key in first_dict:
    # если такой же ключ есть во втором и их значения равны
    if key in second_dict and first_dict[key] == second_dict[key]:
        # добавить в результирующий словарь
        result_dict.update({key: first_dict[key]})
```

Comment: Спасибо! А можно Вас попросить объяснить логику или хотя бы разбить на более простые составляющие построчно. В голове не укладывается понимание конструкции....

Comment: Ну или ссылку на источник, где можно разобрать данный пример.

Comment: @Antony добавил в ответ неоднострочный вариант реализации

Comment: Спасибо! Вот это уровень)

Comment: @Antony можете "Принят" ответ, если нет вопросов по словарям

Answer (score 4):

Преобразовываем наборы пар ключ-значение из обоих словарей в множества, делаем пересечение множеств (т.е. находим элементы, которые есть в обоих множествах), результат превращаем обратно в словарь:

```
print(dict(set(d1.items()) & set(d2.items())))
```

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно разберу про массивы. Не знаком с данной темой.

Comment: @Antony только не массивы (list), а множества (set)